# Why is print() in Lua behaving like This?

Tags: lua

In Lua interpreter when I type

```
>print (12 
>>3)
```

stdin:2: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 1) near '3'

Why am I getting this error?

When we type

```
>a=2 
>a=a+ 
>>1
```

This works fine! Then why not print? What is wrong with print()?

Comment: nothing is wrong with print. it's your syntax ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input is `print (12 <NEWLINE> 3)`, which is a syntax error.

Adding a comma after `12` works fine.